# Prove that this is the solution to the given minimization problem

Tags: optimization

I have the minimization problem

minimize $\displaystyle f_0  = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \mu_i \left( \left( 2^\frac{R_i}{\mu_i} - 1 \right) \right)$

with constraint

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N} \mu_i = 1$

and believe that the solution is

$\displaystyle \mu_i = \frac{R_i}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} R_j}$.

The first derivative is
$\displaystyle f_0^\prime = \sum_{i=1}^{N}  \left( 2^\frac{{R}_i}{\mu_i} - \frac{{R}_i}{\mu_i} \rm{log}(2)2^\frac{R_i}{\mu_i} - 1 \right)$

$N$ and $R_i$ are given. I can show that for $i=2$, $f_0^\prime = 0$, by inserting $\mu_2 = 1 - \mu_1$ in $f_0$, taking the derivative and then inserting the solution.

But how can I show it for any $i$?

I couldn't just insert the solution into the first derivative, so I tried to argue that if it works for $i=2$ it would also work for higher $i$. Or that the problem can always be solved for $i=2$ and then subdivided further. But I am not sure.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Which quantities are given parameter-values, which ones are variables? Why the $L$, the index ${}_0$, and what is $\overline{R_i}\ $?

Comment: thx, I removed the unneeded indices. Calling the cost function $f_0$ is a convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual [Lagrange multiplier method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) works (if you are not familiar with the method, let me recommand reading the WP page before continuing, in particular you must realize that the quantity you denote by $f'_0$ simply does not enter the picture).

For every given $i$, the partial derivatives with respect to $\mu_i$ of the function $f_0$ to be minimized and of the constraint are
$$
2^{R_i/\mu_i}-1-(R_i/\mu_i)\log(2)2^{R_i/\mu_i}\quad\text{and}\quad 1\quad\text{respectively}.
$$
Hence the former must not depend on $i$, that is, for a given $C$,
$$
2^{R_i/\mu_i}(1-\log(2)R_i/\mu_i)=C.
$$
The function $x\mapsto 2^{x}(1-\log(2)x)$ is monotone on $x\ge0$ hence $R_i/\mu_i$ must not depend on $i$, that is, one must have $\mu_i=cR_i$ for a given $c$. Since $\sum\mu_i=1$, $1/c$ is the sum of $R_i$ over $i$ and you are done: the optimal vector $(\mu_i)$ is given by
$$
\mu_i=\frac{R_i}{R_1+\cdots+R_N}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The function $x\mapsto 2^x$ is convex. Therefore by Jensen's inequality for arbitrary $\mu_i\geq0$ with $\sum_{i=1}^N \mu_i=1$ and arbitrary $x_i\in{\mathbb R}$ one has
$$\sum_{i=1}^N \mu_i\ 2^{x_i}\geq 2^\sigma\ ,$$
where $\sigma:=\sum_{i=1}^N\mu_i x_i$ is the weighted arithmetic mean of the $x_i$.
Now put $x_i:={R_i \over \mu_i}$ and obtain 
$$\sum_{i=1}^N \mu_i\ 2^{R_i / \mu_i}\geq 2^{\sum_i R_i}\ .$$
This can be interpreted as follows: Your function $f_0$ of the $\mu_i$ assumes its minimum $2^{\sum_i R_i}-1$ when all $x_i$ are equal to their common arithmetic mean $\sigma$, which in turn means that the $\mu_i$ have to be proportional to the $R_i$.

Answer (score -1):

Just trying to throw some insight on the abstract thinking for the accepted answer: let $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be the function such that $g(x)=2^x(1-x\log2)$. Notice that $g|_{\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}}$ is decreasing and hence injective, therefore $g(R_i/\mu_i)=C$ implies $R_i/\mu_i $ being constant.

Edit: The above statement is sufficient when $\mu_i,R_i$ are assumed positive. Not sure if it is implied in any sense or if it can be derived without such assumption.